# PHP - Real time notification system- supporting all browsers and devices

Tags: php, codeigniter, notifications, real-time, environment

i'm actually using Codeigniter framework.

I was planning to make a simple real time notification system for website users.

The fact is i can see websockets etc .. all new awesome stuffs are not really supported all over the browsers and devices, for example Android mobile is really cutted off.

> So , what i'm wondering now, which is the best way to go, best
>   envoirment to plan for making real time notifications using PHP and
>   Mysql (**I can only use Mysql db no others**)?

at the end which techonologies/frameworks/languages to involve to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a CodeIgniter Framework, here you have a good tutorial. Click [here](http://ericterpstra.com/2013/04/live-updates-in-codeigniter-with-socket-io-and-redis/) and read it. It will help you to use nodejs, socket.io and CodeIgniter together for live updates.

**Update**
Node.js documentations [here](http://nodejs.org/api/)

Comment: Yes yes, I learn a lot from this tutorial, and I also didn't use Redis. I only learn from it for the node.js and socket.io. You can analyze code, and he explain it great. I prefer to read it, and also to read a documentation of Node.js.

Comment: yeah so thank you +1 , i will try figureing out somenthing by that

Comment: Thanks. I update an answer, and add a node.js documentation. If you read in details I am sure that you will be able to do a great notification system.

Comment: node.js and socket.io is good. I am using it for other things. But what if I need a offline notification like inbox or messages as in hey we added this new feature .. check it out. Then what is a good way doing this?